# Can't find a reason for this SQL Error

Tags: mysql, sql

The query is the following:

```
SELECT group,mailId FROM marketinggroups ORDER BY group ASC
```

and here is the CREATE code of the table marketinggroups

```
CREATE TABLE `marketinggroups` (
`group` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'gruppo',
`mailId` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'id della mail'
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And here is the MySql error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'group,mailId FROM marketinggroups ORDER BY group ASC' at line 1

What's wrong with this query? I have used the same syntax in other tables with success.

Comment: `group` is a reserved word.  It needs to be escaped (surrounded by backticks).  Or better yet, use a different name.

Comment: Would also recommend using a different column name but just to add, other than escaping the name, you can also order by 1 asc, since group is the first column in the select list (you can also omit "asc" since that is the default order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group` is a SQL reserved word. Having a column with a reserved names make you this issue. So rename your column name to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the query like below using (backtics), as `group` is a `mysql` reserved keyword.

```
SELECT `group`, `mailId` FROM `marketinggroups` ORDER BY `group` ASC
```